# simple javascritp Slideshow - adding controls

Tags: javascript, slideshow

UPDATED:
Im doing simple lyrics slideshow I used some js slideshow and modified it. 
<strike>My question is, can it be done more simple way - original code had timed autoplay etc?/

All I want is showing/hidding divs - ordered from first - listing with onclicks on prev/next divs</strike>, keys left/right or pgup/pgdn and mouse wheel roll.

[CodePen](http://%20%20%20%20https://codepen.io/rrob/pen/JvOped)

```
//slideshow - 
//https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp 
var slideIndex = 1; showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {   showSlides(slideIndex += n); }
function currentSlide(n) {   showSlides(slideIndex = n); }
function showSlides(n) {

  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: This is a little broad for SO. What is your specific question? There is a Code Review SE if that's what you want.

Comment: Just to do simpler js switching slides.Originaly it contains autoplay, dots on the bottom etc. And I dont know which code I can erase to clean it. And then add controls (arrows, mouse).

Comment: Ok, dots and etc is by experimenting cleaned. Now pls about controling by keyboard?

Comment: Details about your question should be in the question, not comments. Comments can be deleted. Just [edit] the question and add your details.